# Is there a way to whitelist emails on outlook so all their emails don’t go to junk

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

My emails from someone keep going in junk and is there a way to whitelist that email address so that their emails never go to junk on outlook?

Comment: https://clean.email/user/pages/how-to-whitelist-an-email/cleanout@2x.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Try the following process. Below is a process that works for me.

Outlook. Home Tab.  Make sure you can see the email in your Inbox and it is active.

Pull down the Junk Email setting and select "Never Block Sender"

[image]

[image]

The above works in Outlook 2010 and up.

Answer (score 1):

@John is right.
You could try removing this specific email address from your Block Sender list and add it to your safe sender list.

Comment: Yes. Safe Senders list also works.